# how to increase question number and score count

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a quiz app and i was trying to increase the question number and score every time they go to the next question. Also would like to give some feed back when they get it the question right or wrong. Any tips will be greatly appreciated. New to coding and really trying to figure this all out

```
let currentQuestion = 0;

let score = 1;

function renderQuestion() {

document.getElementById("quiz").innerHTML =
`
     <fieldset>
     <legend> ${questions[currentQuestion].question} </legend>
     <input  type="radio" name="option" 
     value="A">${questions[currentQuestion].options[0].option}<br>
     <input type="radio" name="option" 
     value="B">${questions[currentQuestion].options[1].option}<br>
     <input type="radio" name="option" 
     value="C">${questions[currentQuestion].options[2].option}<br>
     <input type="radio" name="option" 
     value="D">${questions[currentQuestion].options[3].option}<br>
     <button id="button" class="submitAnswer"> Submit answer </button>
     <div id="errorMessage">
     </div>
     <div id="feed">
      </div>
    </fieldset>

    `;

    document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", 
  function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    let hasAnswer = false;

    for (let el of document.querySelectorAll("input")) {

        if (el.checked) {

            hasAnswer = true;

            if (el.value === questions[currentQuestion].answer)


    {

                score++;
            }
        }
    }

    if (hasAnswer) {

        if (currentQuestion === questions.length - 1) {

            document.getElementById("quiz").innerHTML = `Your score is 
   ${score}`;
        }

        else {
            currentQuestion++;
            renderQuestion();
        }
    }
      else {
        document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = "Please 
select an answer!";

    }
  });
 }



renderQuestion();
```

Comment: You're going to have to fix/correct a ton of formatting before anyone can help here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to increase the score every time they move to the next question, the easiest way would be to add this:

```
score++;
```

Inside this:

```
else {
    currentQuestion++;
    score++;
    renderQuestion();
}
```

Which is inside this block:

```
if (hasAnswer) {

        if (currentQuestion === questions.length - 1) {

            document.getElementById("quiz").innerHTML = `Your score is 
   ${score}`;
        }

        else {
            currentQuestion++;
            score++;
            renderQuestion();
        }
    }
      else {
        document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = "Please 
select an answer!";

    }
```

Hopefully this helps!